# Power residue when changing level

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I am stuck with the following problem while reading a book:

Assume $x$ is a $k$-th power modulo $p^a$ for a certain off prime $p$ and $a \geqslant 1$. Assume moreover that $p^{a-1} || k$. Is that clear that it is also a $k$-th power modulo $p^b$ for $b \geqslant a$?

The assumption is that $x = y^k + qp^a$ for a certain residue class $y$ modulo $p^a$ and an integer $q$. So that I would like to day it is a $k$-th residue power modulo any $p^b$ for $b \leqslant a$. I guess this has too do with the divisibility assumption, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: That seems to be this question on MO (the 4th one): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300813/number-of-power-residues-modulo-prime-power. However no one answered...

Comment: guessing k isn't higher than the prime power ?